# No ec2 instances are being created when using philips labs terraform aws self hosted module

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, terraform, github-actions

I have been trying to test and implement self hosted runners but the issue is that instances are turning on even after everything is connected. I have followed every step github apps and everything but still the instances are not turning up. Cloudwatch registers the request but for somereason the request to create instances are not working. I have attached the main.tf file clould anyone please help in sorting this issue out.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.44.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region     = var.aws_region
  access_key = "Akey"
  secret_key = "skey"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "random_id" "random" {
  byte_length = 20
}
resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "spot" {
  aws_service_name = "spot.amazonaws.com"
}
module "github-runner" {
  create_service_linked_role_spot = true
  source  = "philips-labs/github-runner/aws"
  version = "2.0.0-next.1"

  aws_region = var.aws_region
  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  prefix = var.prefix

  github_app = {
    key_base64     = "key"
    id = "id"
    webhook_secret = random_id.random.hex
  }

  webhook_lambda_zip                = "lambdas-download/webhook.zip"
  runner_binaries_syncer_lambda_zip = "lambdas-download/runner-binaries-syncer.zip"
  runners_lambda_zip                = "lambdas-download/runners.zip"
  enable_organization_runners = true
  runner_extra_labels         = "default,example"


  # enable access to the runners via SSM
  enable_ssm_on_runners = true

  instance_types = ["m5.large", "c5.large"]
  # Uncomment to enable ephemeral runners
  runner_run_as = "ubuntu"
  enable_ephemeral_runners = false
  # enabled_userdata         = true
  delay_webhook_event      = 0
  runners_maximum_count = 20

  idle_config = [{
    cron      = "* * o-23 * * *"
    timeZone  = "Europe/Amsterdam"
    idleCount = 3
  }]


  # fifo_build_queue = true
  enable_job_queued_check = true
  # override scaling down
  scale_down_schedule_expression = "cron(* * * * ? *)"
}
```

I have tried with ephemeral and isle configs enabling and disabling fifo queue and most other toggles but nothing seems to work.

Comment: "nothing seems to work" - is not specific. What **exactly** is happening? Any errors?

Comment: the webhook api register the event but does not create any ec2 instances even in the case of idle runners no instances ae created nor does it show any error just shows that it registered the event and nothing after that.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I do see the SQS messages coming through and the `scale-up` lambda executing. It "seems" to fail - I see the following logs:

```
Received workflow_job from {my-org}/terraform-aws-github-self-hosted-runners 
{}

[scaleUp] Received event 
{...}
  
GHES API URL: {...}

WARN [scale-runners:  Runtime.handler] Ignoring error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported 
{...}
```

I suspect the `GHES API URL:` *should* have a value after it, but I'm not certain. Also, the final log says it is ignoring an error... Any thoughts?